# How to select a layer from the current map using Python on ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I'm trying to learn how to use Python notebooks on ArcGIS Pro. I'm trying to add a new field to one of the layers on my Map. I added the layers to my map from online. This is the code I have so far:

```py
import pandas as pd
import arcgis
import arcpy

#Create variables that represent the ArcGIS Pro project and map
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('Current') #could switch this to r and location of the map
mp= aprx.listMaps('Map')[0] #Map represents the name of the Map

#Create a variable that represents the default file geodatabase
fgdb=r"C:\Users\428589\Desktop\BEN Priorities\BEN Map"
aprx.defaultGeodatabase=fgdb
arcpy.env.workspace=fgdb
```

However, I am not sure how I can select one of the layers in the map, named "High Injury Network", and how to add a field and then create a score using other fields in the map.

Comment: Please edit your post (title and content) to ask just one specific question.  Eg, "How to select a layer from the current map using Python?".  Other questions can be asked separately (eg, "How to add a field to a layer in Python?")

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways to learn Python in ArcGIS desktop (ArcMap or Pro) is to successfully run the geoprocessing tools manually in Pro and then copy the Python code from the result, if you cannot run it manually successfully then you probably have errors elsewhere such as file formats, permission or locks.  Once you have working code then you can make it dynamic with variables and lists. There is a geoprocessing tool for most tasks that you undertake via the gui such as the geoprocessing tool 'Add Field' https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/add-field.htm.

You can access the Python command from the geoprocessing run button (see drop down menu on button) or the geoprocessing history window (right click on result for various options) https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/basics/geoprocessing-history.htm